# stop gorm from complaining about Unknown column ‘users.deleted_at’ in where clause

Tags: json, go, struct, encoding, go-gorm

How do I stop **gorm** from complaining about **deleted_at** field. I know I can use plain struct **without gorm.Model** but that would mean I **cant add relations to user/other structs**… eg I cannot declare user has one language association in User struct if I dont add gorm.Model but if I add, it would complain about **deleted_at** field which of course doesnt exist. any help is really appreciated. I have tried some combination of tags eg I added DeletedAt field and give it tags 1. gorm: “-” and then I also tried json: “-” to ignore it, but still no luck
This seems very small basic but I couldnt figure sorry I am newbie in golang.

Comment: What you're saying about relationships just isn't true at all.

Comment: You are right. I did added my own answer with explanation as no one else answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found my answer in the [conventions of gorm docs](http://gorm.io/docs/conventions.html)

I've just created my own base model instead using gorm.Model and didnt use deleted_at field on it. And it worked perfectly.

Edit: 
And seems that I was wrong, I can have any base struct and associations will work. Just dont user gorm.Model as base Model.